# Remove line breaks if there are no characters on that line

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to remove linebreaks if there are no characters next to it.
[image]

I'd like to keep Line1, Line2, Line3 untouched but the break after Line3 and before Line1 removed.

I tried:

```
Element.value = Element.value.replace(/\n?![A-z]/g, "");
```

I'm not too good with regex.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.replace(/(\r?\n){2,}/g, '\n').replace(/^\r?\n|\r?\n$/g, '');
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cExMZ/2/)

This regex replaces sequences of 2 or more line breaks with a single line break, then remove leading and trailing line breaks.

Comment: Wow, I never even knew you could use .replace.replace

Comment: @IntelAndBacon `replace` is a string method and it returns a string, so you can chain as as many `replace`, `substr`, `substring` etc. as you'd like. `=]`